# Can't transfer tbox from 1 form to another tbox in another form c#

Tags: c#, textbox, transfer

I have 2 forms, `Form1` is the parent and `ALog` is the child. My goal is to have a textbox's text from `Form1` (`form1textbox`) contents transfer over to a textbox on `ALog` (`alogcheckbox`)

This has to be done on the formload event on `Alog` and when the form shows from a button click on `Form1`

This is what I have currently:

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return form1textbox.Text; }
        set { form1textbox.Text = value; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ALog alogform = new ALog();

        alogform.Show();

    }
}
```

ALog:

```
 public partial class ALog : Form
{
    public ALog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form Alog;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ALog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Form1.LabelText = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

I've seen other questions similar to mine and answers as well, but I can't seem to manage to get this to work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you used the debugger would be my first question.. also this is not that trivial, do a google search there are tons of working examples on internet as well as `stackoverflow` `ALog alogform = new ALog();` you need a public property to hold a string variable in `Alog` Form, also in this line `ALog alogform = new ALog();` you need to assign the value of the string variable prior to the `Alog.show()`

Comment: yes, and I have tried to use the other examples mentioned but I still am unable to see what I'm doing wrong...hence why I am asking here.

Comment: Are you familiar with properties..or method Overloads..? the answered question below gives a great example.. I would suggest copying and pasting the code and stepping thru to understand the code [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_variables.htm) good site you should utilize and bookmark until you become more proficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a constructor to `ALog` that takes the value, and initialize it that way.

`ALog` becomes:

```
public partial class ALog : Form
{
    public ALog(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.alogcheckbox.Text = value;
    }

    public Form Alog;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And from `Form1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ALog alogform = new ALog(form1textbox.Text);

    alogform.Show();
}
```